# is there any data types in oracle that do not support null value without specifying constraints like not null or key constriants

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

1. I just like to know is there any data types in sql or oracle which do not accept null values without specifying null or any key constraints like primary key.
2. Do foreign key accept null values.

Comment: Since SQL is an attempt at a relational database, and relational databases are meant to be based around [Codd's 12 Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules), it would be surprising if a SQL database product violated rule 3.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have a question: "any data types in sql or oracle"  .What does that mean? Sql Server or Oracle? Regardless, to answer your questions:
1) every data type supports null except if they have the not null constraint.

2) foreign key accept null values.

Answer (score 0):

1. All data types allow for null.
2. Yes foreign keys can be null. You need this for optional information. Let's say you have orders and invoices. The order table has an invoice ID, but as the invoice is written later, the order's invoice ID is null at first, but must later contain an ID found in the invoice table.

Answer (score 0):

Not in SQL but you can define your own subtypes in PL/SQL and specify that they do not accept `NULL` values and then use that in your procedures:

```
CREATE PACKAGE types_pkg IS
  SUBTYPE MY_BYTE IS NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL;
END;
/
```

Then you can use them in procedures without redeclaring that they are `NOT NULL` in the procedure signature.

```
CREATE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE print_value(
    value TYPES_PKG.MY_BYTE
  );
END;
/ 

CREATE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE print_value(
    value TYPES_PKG.MY_BYTE
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( value );
  END;
END;
/
```

Calling the procedure with a `NULL` value:

```
BEGIN
  test_pkg.print_value( NULL );
END;
/
```

Throws:

```
PLS-00567: cannot pass NULL to a NOT NULL constrained formal parameter
```